# Porting C++ Code from OpenCV 2.4.8 to OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, opencv

A few months ago I started working on porting quite large code base from using iplimage to cv::Mat so that we could avail of the GPU acceleration provided by OpenCV 3. This included removing some of the deprecated functions unsupported by cv::Mat. In Total it took around 3 weeks to get to a stable though untested version. However, the work focus shifted and the work was benched and was never merged into the master branch. Since then the code has been through a further 3 releases and I feel it woudl take longer to resolve a dodgy merge than to just redo the work.

My question is, has anyone experienced this move and are there any ideas on how I can segregate the move? Or do i simply have to change all of the references again, one by one build at the end and keep my fingers crossed?

Many thanks

Comment: I seem to remember that there was a link to a cheat sheet posted for conversion from OpenCV 2.4->3.0 in response to a question. I'll search around and see if I can dig it up.

Comment: Here you go. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862983/upgrade-opencv-project-to-latest-version